# Is the inverse function smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Imagine that we have a function $Inv$ that maps $A \rightarrow A^{-1}$, where A is an invertible square matrix. now my questions is: how do i see that this function is arbitrarily often differentiable?

Comment: Under what topology on the set of maps you're working with?

Comment: just take the natural toplogy for matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Comment: The inverse is the adjugate matrix divided by the determinant, hence its entries are ratios of two polynomials (i.e. a rational function) in the entries of $A$. So, you are essentially asking why a rational function is infinitely differentiable (provided that the denominator is nonzero).

Comment: @user1551 You could turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The inverse is the adjugate matrix divided by the determinant, hence its entries are ratios of two polynomials (i.e. a rational function) in the entries of $A$. So, you are essentially asking why a rational function is infinitely differentiable (provided that the denominator is nonzero).